# Как PHPStorm использовать как ftp редактор?

Tags: phpstorm

1. Скажите, как эту IDE использовать как ftp редактор? То есть не создать проект с синхронизацией по ftp, а просто заходить на ftp-сервер и редактировать нужный файл.
2. Видел автозамены, например div#id заменяет на `<div id="id"></div>`, как это настроить?

Comment: Самый удобный способ работать по фтп это Atom и Notepad++

Answer (score 5):

Делал удаленный проект по sftp, но на самом деле это не так уж и важно: там можно любой тип соединения выбрать.
Сам не пробовал, но советовали именно sftp(ftp типа глючит), поэтому думайте сами.

Приступим:
File -> New Project from existing files...

Дальше выбираете этот пункт:
Web server is on remote host files are accessible via FTP/SFTP/FTPS

Потом указываете имя вашего проекта(как он будет называться в phpStorm) и локально у вас на машине где он может разместиться.

Далее идут настройки уже самого ftp/sftp и всего, что с ними. Думаю разберетесь.

Comment: я спрашивал, как обойтись без создания нового проекта. мне не нужно скачивание файлов, и принудительное обновление данных на сервере после локального сохранения.

Comment: Правильно поставленный вопрос - половина правильного ответа;)

Answer (score 4):

View -> Tool Windows -> Remote Host.
Это как раз то что нужно, кажется появилось в последних версиях PHPStorm (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.1/remote-host-tool-window.html?origin=old_help).
Достаточно создать пустой проект и использовать эту штуку.

Единственный минус: не аплоадится автоматически! :(. Приходится каждый раз жать Alt+Shift+Q.

Comment: В настройках *Build, Execution, Deployment -> Deployment -> Options* есть пункт *Upload changed files automatically to the default server*. Но работает только, если указан маппинг.

Answer (score 1):

> Видел автозамены, например div#id заменяет на , как это сделать?

В контексте html набираете div#html и нажимаете tab.

Answer (score 0):

Даа, вот эти пляски с ftp всегда напрягают. Я поэтому пользуюсь устаревшим Zend Studio 5.5.1 там очень просто и удобно добавляется ftp, единственное он работает не очень хорошо:

1. Нельзя менять права на папки
2. Плохо загружает большое кол-во файлов

В более новых версиях тот же самый геморой с ftp. Попробуйте, может быть понравится.

Answer (score 0):

Tools -> Deployment -> Configuration

[image: screenshoot]